# Plot rate of change in $x$ axis of list of points

Tags: plotting

I have a list of points, that may have clusters in some of the $x$ axis values, and my goal is to get a function that shows that graphically.

Something like this, but the red function is "hand drawn", it's just for reference.

[image: frequency plot]

The high points of the red plot shows where the clusters are and the low points where are the points that are most isolated.

Comment: I think you can just plot the points in front of their `Histogram` or `SmoothHistogram`.

Comment: or perhaps `DistributionChart[data,BarOrigin->Left]`. See:https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DistributionChart.html

Answer (score 4):

```
values = Transpose[{Join[
     RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1.5, 0.3], 100], 
     RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[3.5, 0.3], 100]], 
    RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1.5, 0.1], 200]}];
Overlay[{ListPlot[values, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 2}}, 
   ImagePadding -> 25], 
  SmoothHistogram[values[[All, 1]], Axes -> False, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, All}}, ImagePadding -> 25]}]
```

[image]